# Синглтон и многопоточность

Tags: java, многопоточность, singleton

Есть, к примеру, класс синглтон:

```
 class Singleton {

   ...здесь инициализация синглтона

   public Date getDate(Date date) {
       return calculateDate(date);
   }

   private Date calculateDate(Date date) {
       Date date = new Date();
       ...здесь определенный алгоритм
   }
}
```

Как он будет работать в многопоточном режиме, когда вызов publlic метода `getDate()` будет одновременно осуществляться с разных потоков?
Предположим private метод `calculateDate()` выполняется долго и много потоков одновременно могут вызывать его. Безопасно ли это?

Answer (score 5):

Проблемы с многопоточностью есть, когда есть разделяемое состояние. Когда один читает, а другой пишет.

Одно из классических решений проблемы многопоточности - иммутабельность, когда объекты нельзяа поменять. А значит пишущего потока быть не может, значит нет состояния, собственно проблемы разделяемых состояний тоже.

В вашем случае на данный момент состояния нет, функция просто принимает параметр и на основе этого параметра, не используя никакие поля класса вычисляет значение. Опасность только в том, что параметр Date изменяемый и может поменятся другим потоком. Поэтому лучше всего делать копию для полной потокобезопасности:

```
private Date calculateDate(Date date) {
    Date date = new Date(date.getTime());
    ...
}
```

Плюс у вас почему в параметр пишется новое значение сразу же, что делает код вообще безопасным полностью, но я так понимаю это просто опечатка )

Если же вы начнете что либо писать в параметр или поля класса - тогда нужно будет думать о многопоточности.

Comment: Я так понимаю, если метод calculateDate в параметрах принимает примитивы или String, то здесь вообще никаких проблем не будет. Но все же никак не могу понять, как в памяти будет одновременно обрабатываться один метод синглтона с разными данными.

Comment: А в чем проблема? При вызове функции, в стек выгружаются параметры функции, указатель текущей инструкции перемещается на адресс фукнции calculate. А функция уже беред даные из стека. Потом вдруг начинает работать другой поток. Текущее состояние (локальные переменые) сохраняются. В стек ложаться новые параметры и указатель текущей инструкции перемещается на эту же функцию calculate. Но уже с нвоыми параметрами в стеке. Переключается контекст обратно, выгружаются старые значения.

Comment: Я перефразирую. параметры хранятся в стеке, а стек у каждого потока свой. Поэтому может без проблем выполнятся одна и таже функция с разными параметрами в разных потоках.